# kafka_exporter does not work on compute instance

Tags: go, apache-kafka, jmx-exporter

I tried setting up kafka_exporter following steps on their [github](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) on a compute Instance (CentOS 7) running Kafka.

When i ran the below command, I am getting the "Error Init Kafka Client":

```
/opt/kafkaexporter/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=kafka1:9092 --kafka.version="2.11.0" --tls.enabled  --log.enable-sarama
```

Would highly appreciate any suggestions to run kafka_exporter on a compute instance running Kafka.

Thank you in Advance,

Console Output:

```
/opt/kafkaexporter/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=kafka1:9092 --kafka.version="2.11.0" --tls.enabled  --log.enable-sarama

INFO[0000] Starting kafka_exporter (version=1.2.0, branch=HEAD, revision=830660212e6c109e69dcb1cb58f5159fe3b38903)  source="kafka_exporter.go:474"
INFO[0000] Build context (go=go1.10.3, user=root@981cde178ac4, date=20180707-14:34:48)  source="kafka_exporter.go:475"
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 Initializing new client
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker kafka1:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 Failed to connect to broker kafka1:9092: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata got error from broker while fetching metadata: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata retrying after 250ms... (3 attempts remaining)
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker kafka1:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 Failed to connect to broker kafka1:9092: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata got error from broker while fetching metadata: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:00 client/metadata retrying after 250ms... (2 attempts remaining)
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker kafka1:9092

[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 Failed to connect to broker kafka1:9092: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata got error from broker while fetching metadata: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata retrying after 250ms... (1 attempts remaining)

[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker kafka1:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 Failed to connect to broker kkafka1:9092: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata got error from broker while fetching metadata: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
[sarama] 2020/03/27 05:47:01 Closing Client
ERRO[0000] Error Init Kafka Client                       source="kafka_exporter.go:210"
panic: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.NewExporter(0xc42017a6f0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x100, 0x8f22f8, 0x0, 0x8f22f8, 0x0, 0x1, 0x8f22f8, ...)
  /go/src/github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter/kafka_exporter.go:211 +0x847
main.main()
  /go/src/github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter/kafka_exporter.go:481 +0x215b
```

I am able to ping to the kafka1 instance

Comment: Ping is good, but can you telnet to it? "_Is your cluster reachable?_" seems to imply you can't.

Comment: why do you run the exporter on another node then the kafka node?

Comment: Thanks for your input @mazaneicha & @rickyA!  I am able to reach my Kafka instance, in fact i am running the kafka_exporter on my Kafka compute instance itself

Comment: does `--kafka.server=localhost:9092` work?

Comment: @RickyA the result is the same

Comment: I found out that we need to convert the Java Keystore & Truststore (JKS) certificates to PEM and use those as inputs (flags) to kafka_exporter.  https://medium.com/processone/using-tls-authentication-for-your-go-kafka-client-3c5841f2a625

Answer (score 0):

After converting the Java Keystore & Truststore (JKS) certificates to PEM and using them as inputs (flags) to kafka_exporter resolved the issue. (as mentioned in https://medium.com/processone/using-tls-authentication-for-your-go-kafka-client-3c5841f2a625)

```
/opt/kafkaexporter/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=kafka1:9092 --tls.enabled --tls.ca-file="/home/kafka_user/serverpub_truststore_go.cer.pem"  --tls.key-file="/home/kafka_user/serverpub_keystore_go.cer.key.pem"  --tls.cert-file="/home/kafka_user/serverpub_keystore_go.cer.pem" --kafka.version="2.11.0" --log.enable-sarama
```

Output:

```
INFO[0000] Starting kafka_exporter (version=1.2.0, branch=HEAD, revision=8306602b58f5159fe3b38903)  source="kafka_exporter.go:474"
INFO[0000] Build context (go=go1.10.3, user=root@981ac4, date=20180707-14:34:48)  source="kafka_exporter.go:475"
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 Initializing new client
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker kafka2:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 Connected to broker at kafka2:9092 (unregistered)
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 client/brokers registered new broker #2 at kafka2:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 client/brokers registered new broker #1 at kafka1:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 client/brokers registered new broker #3 at kafka3:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/28 01:20:38 Successfully initialized new client
INFO[0000] Done Init Clients                             source="kafka_exporter.go:213"
INFO[0000] Listening on :9308                            source="kafka_exporter.go:499"
```